# Get mapreduce output folder using jobid

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to get the mapreduce output folder from a simple java application via the jobClient and runningjob api. I only have the jobID with me.

The running job api shows that it has a getConfiguration method but i am not getting it in my program. i am using version cdh4.5.0

Is there any other way to get the mapred output folder using filesystem api? maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to find from the Job tracker webconsole. Go the JobTracker.jsp select the job and click on the xml link `Job File: hdfs://192.z.z.z:9000/hadoop/mapred/system/job_201401060430_0001/job.xml`. This will show you all the properties of the job. Look for `mapred.output.dir`

Comment: the job file is stored only while the job is running, after the job is complete it is removed from the job file location. If you want to access the job configuration you can find from the job tracker's log location where the file is stored as jobid_conf.xml. You can get all the properties of the jbo from there itself